# Web scraping - I'm getting the labels but not the values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some values from a website but the only thing that I get are the labels. The actual values of the variables that I'm trying to get are empty.

I'm using requests and BeautifulSoup.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.cofidis.pt/cofidis/cofidisredirect.aspx?Prazo=48&IDPartner=6708&Montante=10000&Seguro=0&IDOferta=20719&IDFinalidade=6&IDFinalidadeOption=100&DesignacaoFinalidade=Outros%20Projetos&origem=")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')    
text = soup.find(id="micro-simulador")
print(text.get_text())
```

But I'm getting only the labels:

```py
Resumo do seu pedido

Outros Projetos

Montante

Prazo

Mensalidade

TAEG

Seguro

TAN

MTIC

...
```

The goal is to get the values inside "micro-simulador", like TAEG = 11.0%.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Looking at the html source, those values are not present. You won't be able to get the values using requests and beautifulsoup alone

Comment: there is a json structure response that return those values, but it's pretty messy. I'm not sure which key in the json structure relates the the desired value wanted

Comment: @chitown88 I just sent you the email, tell me what you need please. Thanks for replying so fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the whole json response through the XHR. As far as what exactly you need to pull out, will be up to you, as I don't understand the non-english labels.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.cofidis.pt/Sim/wsGeralRest.svc/MontantePrazos/6708/6'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'           }

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks a lot! Can I just ask you how did you get the 'https://www.cofidis.pt/Sim/wsGeralRest.svc/MontantePrazos/6708/6' url?

Comment: It’s found by looking into the dev tools of the browser, “Network” tab, then XHR.

Answer (score 1):

as those values are inside input tags, you can get them as following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.cofidis.pt/cofidis/cofidisredirect.aspx?Prazo=48&IDPartner=6708&Montante=10000&Seguro=0&IDOferta=20719&IDFinalidade=6&IDFinalidadeOption=100&DesignacaoFinalidade=Outros%20Projetos&origem=")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')    
text = soup.find(id="micro-simulador")
inputs = text.findAll('input')

for input_tag in inputs:
    print(input_tag.get('id'))
    print(input_tag.get('value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As [chitown88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7752296/chitown88) says, there's a JSON request that you can parse and achieve the same result, see the example below:

```py
import requests

ID_PARTNER = 6708
ID_FINALIDADE = 6
PRAZO = 48
MONTANTE = 10000


def parse_request():
    url = 'https://www.cofidis.pt/Sim/wsGeralRest.svc/MontantePrazos/%s/%s' % (ID_PARTNER, ID_FINALIDADE)
    response = requests.request('GET', url)
    if response.ok:
        content = response.json()['COF_GET_MontantePrazos_RestResult']

        for montante_prazo in content['MontantesPrazos']:
            if montante_prazo['MNT'] == MONTANTE:
                montante_prazo['PM'] = list(filter(lambda v: v['PRZ'] == PRAZO, montante_prazo['PM']))
                return montante_prazo


print(parse_request())
```

Output:

```
{
  'PM': [
    {
      'PRZ': 48,
      'TAN': 8.9,
      'MES': 270.29,
      'IDO': 20719,
      'MSA': 254.64,
      'TAEG': 11.0,
      'IDE': 182587376,
      'MNS': 250.07,
      'DCM': 0.0,
      'ITO': 588,
      'PSA': 48,
      'MTI': 12243.36,
      'PRS': 48
    }
  ],
  'MNT': 10000.0,
  'DES': 'Crédito Pessoal',
  'IDP': 6708,
  'IDF': 6,
  'IDS': 1932
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is perfect to get each value individualy